# Making Docker PostgreSql secure - untrusting local connection, username & password max length

Tags: postgresql, docker, security, encryption

## Context

So currently I am creating a setup/launcher script that sets up a secure docker container with PostgreSql database on the client's machine.

To make it really secure, my plan is for the script to:

1. Autogenerate a random username and password
2. Execute `docker run` (with `-d postgres` of course) and with the randomly generated username and password
3. Autogenerate another set of random username and password
4. Create a new [user](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/sql-createuser.html) with the newly generated username and password
5. [`Grant`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-priv.html) the newly created user with appropriate permissions
6. Return the credentials (username & password) of the newly created user and not store (in other word forget) the superuser credentials (username & password)

## Questions

1. What are the limitations of Postgresql's username and password? From [this source](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/200512250003.32306.markc@renta.net), it seems that the username max length is 64 bytes (so 64 characters) and from [this source](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAFh8B%3Dk6N5Y2nknTkmA9WmzbmSxOzb5WL8UAnvaBLK%2BFJn2w8w%40mail.gmail.com) it seems the max password length is 100 bytes (so 100 characters). Is the information accurate (the sources are pretty old, and I might have misunderstood it)? Also, are only allowed characters alphanumerical? Does it support Base64, MD5, or SHA?
2. I noticed that I can [access](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) the Postgres bash without providing the superuser's password. Upon further research, it seems it's due to the fact that upon creation of the Postgres database, local access is trusted as its automatically configured in [`pg_hba.conf`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html). What is the *command* to untrust all connections, including the local one, and any superuser action needs to have a superuser password supplied?
3. Any suggestion to increase the security, even more, that does not involve self-hosting the database instead of having the client hosting it on his/her machine? (I am aware that this is a broad/off-topic question, therefore feel free to ignore this question)

Answer (score 0):

1. username and password length:

   user names are limited to 63 bytes, like all other identifiers (unless you want to rebuild PostgreSQL).

   `src/include/pg_config_manual.h` has:

   ```
   /*
    * Maximum length for identifiers (e.g. table names, column names,
    * function names).  Names actually are limited to one less byte than this,
    * because the length must include a trailing zero byte.
    *
    * Changing this requires an initdb.
    */
   #define NAMEDATALEN 64
   ```

   The maximum length of the password depends on the password encryption method and the authentication used. For `scram-sha-256`, the limit is 1024.

   See `src/common/saslprep.c`:

   ```
   /*
    * Limit on how large password's we will try to process.  A password
    * larger than this will be treated the same as out-of-memory.
    */
   #define MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH     1024
   ```

   The limit of 100 that you are quoting is from the `psql` password prompt, but nobody forces you to use that.
2. default authentication method

   Use the `-A` option during `initdb` to specify a different authentication method.
3. making a docker container safe

   Yes, that is too broad. Essentially, if you have the files that make up the database, you can get at all the data, so I would think that impossible.